# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с rand в php

Tags: php, html

Я нашла в интернете скрипт для тестирования, многое переделала под мою задачу, но не могу разобраться с таким моментом:

```
$otvok=0;
$vopr=15;
$otvno=15;

$query = "SELECT * from vika_users WHERE session='$session';";
$sort=@mysql_query($query);
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($sort);
$time=$row["date_b"]-$row["date_a"];

...

$countd=round($count/$vopr);
$sql_a="";
for($i=1; $i<=$vopr; $i++) {
$a=$i*$countd-$countd+1;
$b=$i*$countd;
$sql_a.="\"".rand($a, $b)."\", ";
}
$date_a=date("U");
$date_b=date("U");
$user=addslashes($_POST["name"]);
$email=addslashes($_POST["email"]);
$ip="127.0.0.1";
$session=addslashes($_GET["session"]);
$query = "SELECT num from vika_users WHERE session='$session';";
$sort=@mysql_query($query); 
$count=mysql_num_rows($sort);
if($count==0) {
if(strlen($user)!=0) {
$sql=<<<END
INSERT INTO vika_users (num, user, email, ip, ball, date_a, date_b, vopros, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9, o10, o11, o12, o13, o14, o15, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12, y13, y14, y15, yes, no, session) 
VALUES (
"", "$user", "$email", "$ip", 0, "$date_a", "$date_b", 0, $sql_a 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "$session"
);
```

Данный скрипт выбирает из базы данных 15 вопросов в разброс и выдает студенту решать. В базе данных должно быть больше вопросов, чтоб скрипт выбирал в случайном порядке.

Мне нужно сделать чтоб было всего 40 вопросов и студенту они выдавались в обычном порядке от 1 до 40. Если в данном случаи я ставлю $vopr=40; и в базе всего 40 вопросов, скрипт не срабатывает и выдает ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста новичку в php, буду очень благодарна.

Comment: покажите ошибку

Comment: в вопросе имя Natali, в базе таблица Vika. что-то неладное

Comment: подозреваю, что число полей в таблице не совпадает. схема таблицы не меняется, а число полей в инсерте - динамическое. должны совпадать по кол-ву. а лучше нормализовать это дело и хранить ответы в другой таблице многое-ко-многому.

Comment: сохранять данные ответов на вопрос мне не обязательно, можно упростить и убрать. Как можно сохранить только количество правильных ответов?

Comment: @NataliGrigor если ток кол-во правильных, то удалите все лишние поля из таблицы, добавьте новое для числа верных, считайте их после ответа юзера накапливая в счётчике и потом пишите это значение в базу.